# Autocompletion with whitespace tokenizer in elasticsearch. Tokenize whitespaces correctly

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an elastic index I want to do autocompletion with.

Therfore i have a suggestField of type `completion` where i put text that should be autocompleted.

```
"suggestField" : {
          "type" : "completion",
          "analyzer" : "IndexAnalyzer",
          "search_analyzer" : "SearchAnalyzer",
          "preserve_separators" : true,
          "preserve_position_increments" : true,
          "max_input_length" : 50
        },
```

With Analyzers:

```
"IndexAnalyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "stop",
                "stopGerman",
                "EdgeNGramFilter"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "MyTokenizer"
            },
"SearchAnalyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "MyTokenizer"
            },
```

Filters and Tokenizer:

```
"filter" : {
            "EdgeNGramFilter" : {
              "type" : "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram" : "1",
              "max_gram" : "50"
            },
            "stopGerman" : {
              "type" : "stop",
              "stopwords" : "_german_"
            }
          },

"tokenizer" : {
            "MyTokenizer" : {
              "type" : "whitespace"
            }
          }
```

My Problem is now that if i query that field the autocompletion only works if i start at the beginning of the text, not for every word.

E.g. i have one value in my suggest field that looks like:  `"123-456-789 thisisatest"`

If i search my suggest field for `123-` i get that value as a result.
But if i search for `thisis` id do not get a result.
This is my Query.

```
POST myindex/_search?typed_keys=true
 {
  "suggest": {
        "completion-term": {
          "completion" : {
              "field" : "suggestField"
          } ,
          "prefix" : "thisis"
        }
    }
 }
```

**The Question: How do I have to change the above setup to get the given value as a result if i search for `thisis` ?**

FYI: If I use the IndexAnalyzer in kibana with an `_analyze` query for `123-456-789 thisisatest` i get the (from my point of view correct) tokens:

```
1
12
123
123-
123-4
123-45
123-456
123-456-7
123-456-78
123-456-789

t
th
thi
this 
thisi
thisis
thisisa
thisisat 
thisisate 
thisisates 
thisisatest
```

Comment: Can you also show what you index for the `completion` field, in the `input`? From a cursory glance, the approach looks like it might benefit more from `search_as_you_type`, rather than completion: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-as-you-type.html

Comment: @RussCam search_as_you_type was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks for the hint. Now i get the desired behaviour.